# cakePHP 3.0 Redirecting to the current page after adding or editing an entity when using Paginator

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I'm using paginator and when I'm for example on page 2 and I want to add or edit an entity it redirects me to the first page of the paginator. What I want is to be redirect to the second page. When I'm on page 3, I want to be redirected to page 3 after adding or editing an entity.

Redirect in controller at the moment:

```
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
```

I also tried to do

```
return $this->redirect($this->referer());
return $this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );
```

But those don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the redirect url in form itself in a hidden field or something else or you can use session .

```
    if(!$this->request->session()->check($some_var))
    {
        $this->request->session()->write($some_var, $this->referer());
    }
```

now  to return

```
 return $this->redirect($this->request->session()->read($some_var));
```